# Найти нужные координаты

Tags: mysql, sql, spatial

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, где я делаю ошибку? Есть координаты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть запрос

```
SELECT ST_Y(coord_point) as lat, ST_X(coord_point) as lng
FROM `customer`
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((54.17489482345622 26.503829956054688, 54.375358319198526 26.503829956054688, 54.375358319198526 27.286605834960938, 54.17489482345622 27.286605834960938, 54.17489482345622 26.503829956054688))'), coord_point);
```

Вроде полигон "закрыт" и все поинты находятся в нём, но не выводятся. Буду благодарен, если подскажете направление куда копать...

Comment: Вот как вы представляете что мы у вас без вашей СУБД найдём ошибку? Пробуйте. Пробуйте попадают ли точки в квадрат - а потом в более сложную фигуру. Отобразите фигуру вашу там в автокаде, мапле или кореле.

Comment: Если не сложно приведите кусочек таблицы customer, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ситуацию.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/a538d433b486429bb1e0bcf7ae074f1c.png

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил. Нужно было все координаты местами поменять. Вот я бестолочь...